# Prevent Outlook Calendar from Automatically Entering Edit Mode

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I am reviewing my Calendar in Outlook 2013, I often click on the date to highlight it.

Now, if I click on the date in the monthly calendar view, Outlook automatically puts me in `Edit` mode, which ***hides all my appointments for that day***.

I've looked through the options, but cannot find anything to disable this behavior.  Does anyone know how to turn this `feature` **off**?

Answer (score 0):

While I have not found a way to avoid it changing into "Edit Mode" when clicking on a date in month view, you can highlight a certain day through other methods besides clicking:

1. Use the Arrow keys to navigate around the page and highlight different pages
2. Ctrl-G to Go To a certain date